# Problem with alignat

Tags: spacing, amsmath, alignat

I am so bad aligning... Anyone see why there is a big space in the function?

Thanks for your help!

```
 begin{alignat*}{2}
 \tau\colon G\times k[V]&\longrightarrow&k[V] \\
 (x,f)&\longmapsto&\tau_{x}(f)=x\cdot f:V&\longrightarrow k \\
 &&v&\longmapsto\tau_{x}(f)(v):=f(x^{-1}\cdot v)
 \end{alignat*}
```

[image: It appears with a space]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/) Please do always show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/). Otherwise (almost) everyone of us has to extend your code snippet to reproduce your problem and to test our suggestions. This would be inefficient. So here is only a not approved suggestion: `alignat` uses right align, left align, right align, left align etc. So you should not use `&` before and after `\longmapsto` (see David's answer for an example).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{2}
 \tau\colon G\times k[V]&\longrightarrow k[V] \\
 (x,f)&\longmapsto\tau_{x}(f)&=x\cdot f:V&\longrightarrow k \\
 &&v&\longmapsto\tau_{x}(f)(v):=f(x^{-1}\cdot v)
 \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is best obtained with a simple `align*` and a nested `aligned`. I took the opportunity to replace `:=` with `\coloneq` from `mathtools` so  the colon and the equal sign have the same axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     \tau\colon G\times k[V]&\longrightarrow k[V] \\
     (x,f)&\longmapsto\begin{aligned}[t]\tau_{x}(f)=x\cdot f\colon V&\longrightarrow k \\
     v&\longmapsto\tau_{x}(f)(v)\coloneqq f(x^{-1}\cdot v)\end{aligned}
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]